# Google Maps API not showing at all using HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

For the first time I'm trying to incorporate the Google Maps API into a website and it's not working at all. I can't tell if there's something wrong with the code and I'd like to rule that out before trying to create another API Key

I've moved the  tag around and tried different styling approaches, but it just doesn't show anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function initMap() {
            var location = { lat: -30.0327268, lng: -51.2095745 };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                zoom: 4,
                center: location
            });
        }

    </script>

    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBDXh6FfycwxdCaHUbrCWkswSarA77kowY&callback=initMap">
        </script>
    <title>

    </title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map {
            height: 500px;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="map"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Google Maps API URL incorrect. It is https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js ..

Comment: Look at the error message in your browser's developer console. What does it say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL in the script that you are using is incorrect.

**You are using:** https://maps.googleapis/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBDXh6FfycwxdCaHUbrCWkswSarA77kowY&callback=initMap

**The correct URL:** https://maps.googleapis**.com**/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBDXh6FfycwxdCaHUbrCWkswSarA77kowY&callback=initMap

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The below line was not added correctly,

It should be in this form

Below is the updated code in which map is working fine..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function initMap() {
                var location = { lat: -30.0327268, lng: -51.2095745 };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                    zoom: 4,
                    center: location
                });
            }
        </script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBDXh6FfycwxdCaHUbrCWkswSarA77kowY&callback=initMap"
            async defer></script>
        <title>
        </title>
        <style>
            * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            }
            #map {
            height: 500px;
            width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "The below line was not added correctly" - It would be helpful if you said something about _which_ line you are referring to.

Comment: This line  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBDXh6FfycwxdCaHUbrCWkswSarA77kowY&callback=initMap"
            async defer></script>

Comment: Above line is the correct one...Your line given line in code was wrong..